# Firebase Hosting - how to creating a publicly accessible folder?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase Hosting to host my React application (I'm using Webpack). I need to create a publicly accessible folder on my website and upload a file to it, like this: *https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json*. Locally, I've created the top level *.well-known* folder with *assetlinks.json* in it and can now access the file at *localhost:9562/.well-known/assetlinks.json*. I then deployed my project to Firebase, but *https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json* displays a blank page.

Comment: It sounds like your `.well-known` folder is not being deployed. What is deployed when you run `firebase deploy` is controlled through the `firebase.json` configuration file. For the configuration options in that file, see the Firebase documentation for it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config

Answer (score 0):

Files can only be deployed to Firebase Hosting by deploying content with the Firebase CLI, or by using the [new REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reference/rest/).  There is a [detailed example of how to perform an upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy).

If you want to use the REST API to allow individuals to upload content, that's something you're going to have to build yourself, it's very much non-trivial to implement, and is outside the scope of a full answer on Stack Overflow (too broad).  But you could certainly try to accomplish this.

It might be easier to route requests through Cloud Functions to serve the actual content, since deploying with the CLI also removes all existing content that you uploaded with the REST API (if it doesn't also exist in the correct place on the deploying machine).

Basically, you committing to a lot of code and architecture to make this happen.